# MongoDB Java CodecConfigurationException Cannot find a public constructor for

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to create a Java program that reads and writes complex objects to and from a MongoDB, for example...

```
public class GameCharacter {
    public String name;
    public Weapon weapon;
    public Armor armor;

    public GameCharacter(String name, Weapon weapon, Armor armor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
        this.armor = armor;
    }
}
```

I have managed to write it by setting this codec, and I can check in the database that all the data is correctly written in the right structure:

```
        CodecRegistry defaultCodecRegistry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        PojoCodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build();
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(defaultCodecRegistry, fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));

        MongoDatabase characterDatabase = mongoDatabaseConnectionPool.getDatabase(CHARACTER_DATABASE_NAME);
        characterDatabase = characterDatabase.withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
        MongoCollection<GameCharacter> characterCollection = characterDatabase.getCollection(CHARACTER_COLLECTION_NAME, GameCharacter.class);

        Character testCharacter = new Character ("Sylvia Zerin", testWeapon, testArmor);
        characterCollection.insertOne(testCharacter);
```

...however, when trying to read the GameCharacter from that database again like this:

```
        FindIterable<GameCharacter> characters = characterCollection.find();
```

...then the following error message appears:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Decoding into a 'GameCharacter' failed with the following exception:

Cannot find a public constructor for 'GameCharacter'.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
```

This is confusing for me, since I provided a public constructor for the GameCharacter class. It is not clear to me why the program fails to find it.

Following the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800882/save-list-of-interface-objects-using-mongo-driver-for-java?noredirect=1&lq=1), I have also tried the following to set the codec:

```
        ClassModel<GameCharacter> gameCharacterClassModel = ClassModel.builder(GameCharacter.class).enableDiscriminator(true).build();


        CodecRegistry defaultCodecRegistry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(defaultCodecRegistry, fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(gameCharacterClassModel).automatic(true).build()));
        return pojoCodecRegistry;
```

...however, that only slightly changes the error message to:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Cannot find a public constructor for 'GameCharacter'.
```

What do I have to do in order to be able to retrieve the GameCharacterObject from the MongoDB again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

The error message is somewhat misleading. Actually, the problem is that it needs an **empty** constructor **without arguments**, so naturally the constructor in my class above will not work. The exact requirements as defined [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/bson/pojos/) are as follows:

> By default all POJOs **must** include a public or protected, empty, no arguments, constructor.

Thus, the problem can be solved by changing the GameCharacter class to look as follows:

```
public class GameCharacter {
    public String name;
    public Weapon weapon;
    public Armor armor;

    public GameCharacter() {
    }

    public GameCharacter(String name, Weapon weapon, Armor armor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
        this.armor = armor;
    }
}
```